# Replacing a text value in a table cell with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am really struggling to mask a data value with Javascript. I work at a school, and they are doing away with "traditional" grading. As such, they don't want their gradebook to display percentages, but instead show words based on percentages (yeah I know). I would like to replace the % value with a word string. With this JS, it correctly alerts me all the values, but the return value never replaces the % value in the cell. What am I missing? I am extremely new to JS so it may be a simple mistake.

```js
$('.percentage').each(function() {
  var corrected = $(this).html();
  corrected = parseFloat(corrected);
  alert(corrected);
  switch (true) {
    case (corrected < 48.75):
      return 'Unsatisfactory';
      break;
    case (corrected < 61.25):
      return 'Approaching ';
      break;
    case (corrected < 73.75):
      return 'Approaching+ ';
      break;
    case (corrected < 86.25):
      return 'Meeting ';
      break;
    case (corrected < 94.9):
      return 'Meeting+ ';
      break;
    case (corrected <= 100):
      return 'Exceeding ';
      break;
    default:
      return 'N/A';
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do. It parses the text of the cell and replaces it with a string-value based on the current score.

```js
$(".score").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.text(() => {
    var num = parseFloat($this.text());
    var val;
    if (num < 48.75)
      val = 'Unsatisfactory';
    else if (num < 61.25)
      val = 'Approaching ';
    else if (num < 73.75)
      val = 'Approaching+';
    else if (num < 86.25)
      val = 'Meeting';
    else if (num < 94.9)
      val = 'Meeting+';
    else if (num <= 100)
      val = 'Exceeding';

    return val;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Score</td>
    <td class="score">48.75</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Score</td>
    <td class="score">38.25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Score</td>
    <td class="score">85.12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Score</td>
    <td class="score">67.50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Score</td>
    <td class="score">87.80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Score</td>
    <td class="score">10.50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Score</td>
    <td class="score">96.50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The class on the td makes sure you're parsing only cells with an actual score.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a value from `$().each` won't serve your purpose. You want to change `innerText` on the elements you iterate over:

```js
$('.percentage').each(function() {
  var corrected = $(this).html();
  corrected = parseFloat(corrected);
  let text;

  switch (true) {
    case (corrected < 48.75):
      text = 'Unsatisfactory';
      break;
    case (corrected < 61.25):
      text = 'Approaching ';
      break;
    case (corrected < 73.75):
      text = 'Approaching+ ';
      break;
    case (corrected < 86.25):
      text = 'Meeting ';
      break;
    case (corrected < 94.9):
      text = 'Meeting+ ';
      break;
    case (corrected <= 100):
      text = 'Exceeding ';
      break;
    default:
      text = 'N/A';
  }

  $(this).text(text)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="percentage">40</div>
<div class="percentage">72.65</div>
<div class="percentage">100</div>
```

Here `$().text` does exactly this. You could also use vanilla JS:

```
this.innerText = text;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got 2 perfect responses in just minutes. That makes a lot of sense, but couldn't see it for the trees. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome :) Still note that you can accept only one answer. And you generally want to accept the one you used. However for each answer you find useful, you can upvote it.